# How to add rows to make all subjects have the same number of visits

Tags: r, reshape

I have a longitudinal data from human beings. But their follow times are not same with each other. Say subject with id=1 has three visits, subject with id=2 has 1 visit. The maximum visits in the subjects are four.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6o5p.png)

Now, I want to reshape the data set. I want to all subject have 4 visits, like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39OT1.png)

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput()` instead of posting pictures.

Comment: Hi tmfmnk, sorry I didn't know dput() before. arg0naut helped me solve it already. I'll remember to use it next time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  complete(rn = 1:4) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

Comment: Hi arg0naut, It worked well! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Next time please post your example data frame according to the rules. Also consider accepting the answer if it helped.